# The Podcast category has disappeared from library in iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod, itunes-store

The 'Podcast' category has disappeared from the 'Library' in my iTunes library.

This means that I can't download any podcasts and the auto update function isn't working. My existing podcasts are still on my hard drive, but not in iTunes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked whether *Podcasts* are set to be shown in your iTunes Preferences?

[image]

Comment: I agree.  I just reinstalled everything on my computer and iTunes defaulted to not showing podcasts.